# Copy opportunity information to custom object using a button

Tags: custom-object, opportunity, custom-field

I'm trying to create a new custom object when an opportunity is closed won. For that I chose to use a button in the opportunity's page layout to create a new custom record. I want to fill automatically some field of the new custom object with information from the opportunity.

I have tried "URL hacking to prepopulate fields" but it seems it only works for the classic salesforce.

Anyone has an idea how could I do this using flow or process builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL hacks has been replaced by Quick action in Lightning Experience. You can set predefined values for your field values included in action.

> When you create actions, use predefined field values to set a value
>   for a field. Predefined values can help ensure consistency and make it
>   faster and easier for users to create records.

Steps to follow:-

1. Click the name of an action in the Buttons, Links, and Actions list
   or the Global Actions list.
2. On the action detail page, click New in the Predefined Field Values
   list.
3. Select the field you want to predefine a value for.
4. Specify the value for the field. For single-select picklists, you can specify both a specific value
   and a formula value.
5. If you set both, the formula value takes precedence over the
   specific value. Click Save.

Read more here:- [Set Predefined Field Values for Quick Action Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=predefined_field_values.htm&type=5) and [Understand How Actions Work in Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_migration_customization/lex_migration_customization_actions)

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me a lot!